# $R$ be local and suppose $x ∈ R$ satisfies $x^2 = x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

If we let $R$ be local and suppose $x ∈ R$ satisfies $x^2 = x$, then I have to show that $x = 0$ or $x = 1$.

A commutative ring $R$ with $1$ is called local if $R − R^×$ is an ideal of $R$.

If we let $x, y ∈ R$, then I was thinking of the expansion of the equation $(x + y)^2$ = $x + y$. But I am not sure how to proceed from here and if this is even the right way to tackle this problem.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging, we have
$$0= x^2 - x = x(x-1)$$

If $x\neq 0,1$, that means that both $x$ and $x-1$ are both nonzero zero divisors, and in particular non-units. Since $R$ is local, they must both be in the unique maximal ideal. But that means
$$x - (x-1) = 1$$
is in that maximal ideal, so the maximal ideal isn't proper, a contradiction.

So it is only possible that $x=0$ or $x=1$, which of course both satisfy that relation.